# Ag grid Angular 2+ , Way to supress multiple cell selection

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

Is there any gridConfig property to suppress multiple cell selection in ag-grid?
When I select cells using <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I don't want multiple cells to be selected.

Comment: you dont want multiple select ? right ?

Comment: Yes , I don't want multiple cell selection . Don't confuse it with row selection.

Comment: you want to select multiple cell ?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want  the feature of selecting multiple rows, you can set **rowSelection** property to **'single'**

Comment: No , Question is about multiple cell selection.